# MVC5 disable textbox based on another textbox value

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a mvc5 project with ability to create;edit and delete records.
There are 3 textboxes.

Based on value in textBox1, I want to disable TextBox3 and 4;

```
if frequency.Value='Weekly' 
{
   Disable TextBox_BiWeekly 
   Enable TextBox3_Weekly
}
if frequency.Value='BiWeekly'
{
   Disable TextBox3_Weekly
   Enable TextBox4_BiWeekly
}
```

This is part of code in Edit.cshtml

```
    <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.frequency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = ".col-form-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.frequency)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.frequency, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weekly, htmlAttributes: new { @class = ".col-form-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Weekly)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Weekly, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BiWeekly, htmlAttributes: new { @class = ".col-form-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.BiWeekly)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.BiWeekly, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am not sure how to disable or enable Textboxes

Thanks MR

Comment: Your UI is not correct for what you are asking. If `frequency` can only have fixed values ("Weekly" or "BiWeekly") then you should be generating a dropdownlist or radio buttons for selection. And you only need one property/textbox for whatever it is that you enter in your current `Weekly` or `BiWeekly` textboxes

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this would be in JavaScript so that the textboxes can enable/disable on the fly based on the value of your frequency input.

Something like:

```
$(function() {
    EnableDisableFrequency();
    $('#Frequency').change(function() {
        EnableDisableFrequency();    
    });
});
function EnableDisableFrequency() {
    if ($('#Frequency').val() === "Weekly") {
        $('#BiWeekly').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#Weekly').prop('disabled', false);
    } else if ($('#Frequency').val() === "BiWeekly") {
        $('#BiWeekly').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#Weekly').prop('disabled', true);    
    }
}
```

My JavaScript is a bit rusty but I'm pretty sure that should work.
I would however agree with Stephen Muecke that your Frequency input should be a dropdownlist.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Frequency, Model.FrequencyList)
```

Just define FrequencyList in your ViewModel as a List that contains all potential values which I assume is just Weekly and BiWeekly

```
FrequencyList = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "Weekly",
                    Value = "Weekly"
                },
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = "BiWeekly",
                    Value = "BiWeekly"
                }
            };
```

The JavaScript can remain the same.